# List.Add() only adding the last row an intended set of elements in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, file-io

I apologize if the title is not very clear on what exactly it is that I'm asking. But I am writing code for reading data from a comma-separated file of floating point numbers (the data is assumed to be structured, with 3 columns in all rows and no null values), where each number in a row will be stored in a float array of size 3. Each of these arrays would then be sequentially stored in a List object.

So far, after trying my best to thoroughly trawl this website for answers, I came up with this code:

```
string filename = @"D:\TestFiles\floats.bin";

List<float[]> field_array = new List<float[]>();
string[] field_array_row;
float[] field_float_num = new float[3];


Console.WriteLine("Individual parsed rows:");
using (StreamReader parser = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    string line;
    while((line = parser.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        field_array_row = line.Split(',');
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            field_float_num[i] = float.Parse(field_array_row[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",field_float_num));
        field_array.Add(field_float_num);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("\nfield_array Output:");

foreach (float[] x in field_array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", x));
}
```

The floats.bin file was just a dummy file I made for testing this code out, and it looks like this:

3.1, 5.6, 8.9

6.1, 2.3, 2.1

2.2, 7.9, 1.5

3.2, 9.8, 2.4

However, on running this code and looking at the output of the final Console.WriteLine statements, I see that all 4 elements that got stored in the List are the same array (i.e. the one that got parsed last). I am unsure what exactly is happening here. I could be missing something very obvious but I am unable to see it. I tried looking the Console output at every step of the While loop here, and it seems like on each step, the subsequent elements do get added to the list, but they also replace every prior element with itself. Screenshots of the console output are attached:

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15zsW.png)

[Each iteration of the While loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QCNh.png)

Comment: You're adding to the List a reference to the same Array. When you change the values in this Array, all references point to the same object (the Array is a Reference Type), which *contains* the latest value you have inserted

Comment: @Jimi Thank you! I should have kept in mind how C# deals with such data structures. I suppose I'll have to declare a new Array with the new values for every iteration and discard the old one?

Comment: @Jimi  I just changed field_array.Add(field_float_num) to field_array.Add(field_float_num.ToArray()), which makes a copy of the array, and it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the same thing you did with the field_array_row, it would look something like this:

```
        List<float[]> field_array = new List<float[]>();
        string[] field_array_row;
        float[] field_float_num;

        Console.WriteLine("Individual parsed rows:");
        using (StreamReader parser = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = parser.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Here you initialize your array
                field_float_num = new float[3];

                field_array_row = line.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    field_float_num[i] = float.Parse(field_array_row[i]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", field_float_num));
                field_array.Add(field_float_num);
            }
        }
```

This is because the array always keeps the same value in memory.

I hope this help you.